# How to improve a Java build server's performance?

Tags: performance, build-server

We are setting up a new server for integration build. The original integration server can finish the "mvn install" in 3 minutes in a Linux box. Now by moving to a Windows 2012 server on VM, it's down to 9 minutes. The "mvn test" part alone costs 7 minutes. Lots of those tests are following the same pattern: 1. Start a fresh JVM 2. Load test data from files/excel spreadsheets into in-memory database 3. Run queries against that database, validate results

In your opinion, how can we improve this VM's performance? The server already has 16GB of Memory, 256GB of space, 8 vCPUs.

And in general, as a build server, most of work are like this:
1. Read the thousands of files from the workspace,
2. Compile the above source code,
3. Generate thousands of .class files.
4. Jar/Zip these thousands of files.
5. Copy the jars zips files to somewhere else.

These seems more workload on CPU and Disk I/O rather more than RAM, right?

Thanks Jirong

Comment: as far as i know, javac can only run single-threaded... so nothing like in gcc with the -j switch. so, this leaves you with your common bottlenecks, disk i/o, cpu performance, and plenty of *fast* ram. SSD's will help, so will a fast network connection if you checkout fresh for each build. Also, why did you move to windows for your build server? windows has a lot more "stuff" going on in the background that may be effecting performance for your builds. your linux box was probably lean-n-mean.

Answer (score 2):

Our build server performance was increased by increasing the disk subsystem performance.
We now run 4 fast SSD's in hardware RAID 10.

To confirm disk is your performance bottle neck watch the disk subsystem IO compared to your theoretical and look at the latency because when the latency is constantly high you have a problem.

In Windows you can use Perfmon or Windows Resource Monitor. 
In Linux use iostat. 
VMWare vshpere client has graphs on performance tab for disk subsystem.

Comment: +1. Not doing jave but C#/C++ - same here. Build servers are like databases - the LOVE IO subsystems and gladly suck up whatever budget you deploy there. SSD are nearly a must due to low latency that is stable with parallel accesses. And IO is normally also the weak point of any virtualization setup ;)

Comment: +1: I'd emphasize disk latency. Regardless of the theoretical limits of your system, if a single 4K read or write is taking longer than 10ms, then you have hit the **practical** limit of your disk system.

Comment: @surfasb, Thanks for the information. I kind of know how to read the CPU and RAM usage, but don't know how to interpreter the disk i/o info in Windows Performance Monitor. While i am looking into it now. Is there a simple way to benchmark the disk i/o? e.g.how can I do your "single 4K read or write is taking longer than 10ms" test?

Comment: @sufasb, does this IO looks ok to you? http://tinypic.com/r/51t64i/8

Comment: You can benchmark the disk IO subsystem with http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html or http://www.iometer.org/

Comment: @Sam, thanks, I already started running this iometer: http://greg.porter.name/wiki/HowTo:iometer. I'll post the results when it's done.

Comment: Let us know how it goes, The image you uploaded showed high usage on the C drive, is this isolated the F drive? Which disk has the source on it?

Comment: @user2784896: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/02/07/measuring-disk-latency-with-windows-performance-monitor-perfmon.aspx. The **Disk Sec/ per Read/Write** Performance Counter tells you how many seconds it takes to complete a 4K operation.

Comment: @Sam, your tools can run instantly without any setup, the result is here: http://tinypic.com/r/1z4wyrk/8. The left is my PC, and right is the server on VM. Now how can I prove the disk i/o is the bottleneck, using e.g. Windows Performance Monitor?

Comment: @Sam, I put everything on C:\, don't know where is the E:\ drive. I want to ask the SA when I am done the benchmark.

Comment: Separating the IO for the OS and Pagefile from the Build is important. The numbers you have got sugest to me a single SSD or a pair of quick 15K disks. Our old build server had a pair of OCZ Vertex SSD striped and they hit 22mb/s read and 68MB/s write @4K. Do you have to visualise?

Comment: @Sam As you can see, my PC's disk is 100 times slower than the server, but the test runs faster in my PC. This means disk speed is not the bottleneck. We've increased the RAM from 16 to 32G, no impact at all. So left with the CPU and network. The test is just run "mvn clean install", after the first time, should be no internet access is required (is it?). So now left only with CPU? I notice when the test runs on my PC, the CPU is at 80%, but on server it's only 15%. How can I monitor the CPU which is a VM?

Comment: @Sam, can you recommend a simple tool to benchmark the CPU of the VM? Thanks.

Comment: @user2784896 try http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm I don't know how well it will work in a VM though? Have you checked the CPU priority for the VM?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be generalized to just about **any** situation:

1. Start collecting metrics (RAM, IO, CPU, network, etc.)
2. Apply load to system
3. Analyze metrics to identify bottlenecks
4. Mitigate bottlenecks
5. GOTO 1

Comment: Thanks for your information. The problem is this "Analyze metrics to identify bottlenecks" requires knowledge.

Comment: @user2784896 As does programming. If you are not willing to learn basics, there is always McDonalds waiting for some burger server. Seriously - it DOES require basic knowledge, and as someone having a build server (i.e. not a total amateur) take some pride and do not opppose learning, especialyl when basically told where to look (by another answer).

Comment: Yes indeed it does. Sounds like something you should research, try out, and then if you have questions, come back and ask a well-scoped, well-researched question about it.

Comment: Up to now, I get almost the same result form both my pC and the server. This give me a hint that the spec of the machine is no longer an issue. I see 80% of time spent in the Test phone of a particular module. Lots of those tests are following the same pattern: 1. Start a fresh JVM 2. Load test data from files/excel spreadsheets into in-memory database 3. Run queries against that database, validate results. This phase takes almost the same time in my pC and server. They told me it's faster in a Linux box. So it's the JVM performance on different platform?