# Request Timeout when performing load/scalling test

Tags: centos7, timeout

I am trying to check load/scaling testing using 2000 request per minute with loader.io it shows timeout for many requests.

How to resolve such issue on server?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be a multitude of reasons, but essentially *something* is limiting the performance of your web application. Given that your average response time is over 1 second (with a massive std deviation), handling 33 requests per second will be tough in its present state.

To quote EEAA:

> The answer to your question can be generalized to just about any
>   situation:
>
> 1. Start collecting metrics (RAM, IO, CPU, network, etc.)
> 2. Apply load to system
> 3. Analyze metrics to identify bottlenecks
> 4. Mitigate bottlenecks
> 5. GOTO 1

https://serverfault.com/a/579503/362146

Comment: I am having watch on the load, added load balancer with scalling but seems load balancing is not used. Sometime I see cpu is over 80% on reckspace